# Generate unique key for users with same email-address

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

We have a table with orders of customers like:

```
CREATE TABLE `orders` (
    `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `number` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
    `ordered` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
    `email` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    ...
);
```

The table is already filled with data. I need to add a field:

```
`user` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
```

which contains a unique number for each customer. A customer is defined by the same email-address, so all orders with the email 'test@example.com' should get a 1, with 'something_else@example.com' should get a 2 and so on.

For this 'user'-number it doesn't matter if it starts with 1 or is somehow incrementing, it just should be different for every email-address.

Is there a way to do this in one SQL-statement? I know how to do it with some php-code for example, but we where curious if it's possible just with SQL. We know it would be a better design if there was a table "customer", but it's not our design, we just trying to fix the worst things ;)

Comment: start by normalizing your databse and then write the code, that select the uniwue id from table customers and adds it to the orders.

Comment: Yes it is *possible* with SQL, but I think you **shouldn't** design it that way. Your database should really have a many to many relationships, or at least one to many, I believe you want to get more than one order per customer.

Comment: The title of your question(" unique key for users with same email-address") is not clear in relation to what you write to explain your problem.  When you create a unique key for email-addresses, you can only have 1 order per email-address, and that seems not what you want/need.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to do what you describe in one SQL statement.

Even if you didn't care to make the user id unique per email, your ALTER TABLE wouldn't work. You show adding a column that is NOT NULL but has no DEFAULT. So what value is it supposed to add to the table, given that the table has rows in it? It can't use NULL, and it has no DEFAULT value. You can't add the column as an AUTO_INCREMENT because you already have an `id` column that is AUTO_INCREMENT, and MySQL doesn't allow a table to have two such columns.

Here's the way I'd do it:

```
CREATE TABLE customers (
 id INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
 email VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO customers (email)
SELECT DISTINCT email FROM orders;

ALTER TABLE orders ADD COLUMN user_id INT UNSIGNED; -- this allows NULLs until we fill it

UPDATE orders JOIN customers USING (email)
SET orders.user_id = customers.id;
```

Before the next step, make sure that it has populated `orders.user_id` the way you think is correct. Once you drop the `orders.email` column, there's no undo. It would be a good idea to make a backup first.

```
ALTER TABLE orders DROP COLUMN email,
  MODIFY COLUMN user_ID INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL; -- disallow NULLs from now on
```